# What is the processing order for Windows Server 2016 DHCP Policies with overlapping conditions?

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2016

I am trying to understand the DHCP Priority / behavior for DHCP Policies with Windows Server 2016.  In my scenario, I have perhaps an overlapping condition on two policies.   One policy matches on Mac Address partial with a wildcard to match all IP Phones from a Vendor.  I then have a more specific policy that matches with Or conditions on several Mac Addresses.

It appears the most specific Policy is not getting applied based on the Active Leases screen showing which policy is applied to the lease.  I have different options set for the more specific policy.

The processing order is set that the most specific policy has a lower number than the "wildcard" policy.

Comment: `So, what happens when a DHCP client satisfies the conditions of more than one policies? Every policy has a processing order associated with it. It is essentially the priority of that policy and helps in deciding which policy needs to be applied if multiple policies match a client. A policy with a higher priority (numerically lower processing order) precedes over a policy with a lower priority (numerically higher processing order).`

Comment: @joeqwerty, so if I'm understanding correctly, I have two satisfying polices, if the one has a priority of 2 (in this case the specific one that matches on full MAC address) or 3, then I should be expecting that 2 is selected as the policy and it's DHCP options are used, correct?  If that is the case, that's not what I'm experiencing in my environment at the moment.